# EJS Tags with ChartJS?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, chart.js, ejs

Is it possible to use EJS tags to add data to a graph? Here is my current graph's data:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myChart');
var data = {
    labels: ["One", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "My First dataset",
            backgroundColor: "rgba(255,99,132,0.2)",
            borderColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
            borderWidth: 2,
            hoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(255,99,132,0.4)",
            hoverBorderColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
            data: [10, 20, 81, 56, 55, 40],
        }
    ]
};
```

I'm wanting to do something like this:

```
labels: ["<%= currentUser.datapoint1 %>", "<%= currentUser.datapoint2 %>", "<%= currentUser.datapoint3 %>"]

data: [<%= currentUser.datapoint10 %>, <%= currentUser.datapoint11 %>]
```

How would I accomplish using EJS tags to populate the graphs data? (NOTE: The EJS tag info would have already been saved the user before the chart needs to be generated)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can use EJS tags or any other similar tag used across the various `view` javascript frameworks (e.g. handlebars, spacebars in meteor, ejs, etc.).  Chart.js is initialized at runtime, so it has no knowledge of how the data made its way into the file (e.g. it doesn't know...nor does it care...that your javascript was pre-processed and generated).

The format of the tag itself just has to do with the variables in which you stored your data.  I would recommend storing your `labels` and `data` in arrays and using `JSON.stringify()`.

```
// defined in your app
var labels = ['label 1', 'label 2', ...];
var data = [datapoint1, datapoint2, ...];

// in your EJS file.
var canvas = document.getElementById('myChart');
var data = {
  labels: <%- JSON.stringify(labels); %>,
  datasets: [
    {
      label: "My First dataset",
      backgroundColor: "rgba(255,99,132,0.2)",
      borderColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
      borderWidth: 2,
      hoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(255,99,132,0.4)",
      hoverBorderColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
      data: <%- JSON.stringify(data); %>,
    }
  ]
};
```

Comment: Great answer. The key to what I was looking for is having the JSON.stringify INSIDE the tags.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use `JSON.stringify()` in EJS tags. You can do

```
labels: <%- JSON.stringify(data.labels); %>,
data: <%- JSON.stringify(data.datasets.data); %>
```

It's based on your `data` variable. So, you may need to adjust this code accordingly.

Comment: Where does that line of code go?  The code I wrote does not have the variables: data.labels or data.datasets.data  It has graphs.name and graphs.myData   I'd like to access this variable in the javascript code of  charts.ejs but I do not see exactly how to do it.

Comment: The line const graphs = <%= JSON.stringify(graphs) %>; did not work.  Should this be: graphs: <%= JSON.stringify(graphs) %>;

Answer (score 0):

An example, modifying the [Google Chart Quickstart Example](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/quick_start) would help out a great deal. I attempted the below with no luck.

Two files:
chart.js to create the data and chart.ejs template to be renderedL:

Here's what I put together so far:
**chart.js**

```
import { dirname } from "path";
import express from "express"
import { fileURLToPath } from "url";
const __dirname = dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url));
let myData = [
  ['Mushrooms', 3],
  ['Onions', 1],
  ['Olives', 1],
  ['Zucchini', 1],
  ['Pepperoni', 2],
  ['Pineapple',12],
  ['Green Peppers',22]
  ]
  
  let myGraph ={}
  myGraph.name="First Chart"
  myGraph.myData=myData

  const app = express();

  app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    const templatePath = __dirname+"/views/chart.ejs";
    res.render(templatePath,{ graphs: myGraph })
    
});

  app.listen(3000, () => {
    //openBrowser('http://localhost:3000');
    console.log("Server running on localhost:3000")
  });
```

---

and **chart.ejs**

This is what I have so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

</html>
<html>

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['corechart'] });
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawGraphs);


        function drawGraphs() {
            appendDivToBody(graphs.name, 'width: 1200px; height: 500px');
        const graphs = <%= JSON.stringify(graphs) %>;
            graphs.forEach(g => {
              appendDivToBody(g.name, 'width: 1200px; height: 500px');
              drawGraph(g.name, g.myData);
            });
        }

        function drawGraph(graphName, graphData) {
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data.addColumn('string', 'Toppings');
            data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
            data.addRows(graphData);
            var options = {
                title: `${graphName}`,
                'width': 500,
                'height': 300
            };
            var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById(graphName));
            chart.draw(data, options);
        }

        function appendDivToBody(id, style) {
            var div = document.createElement('div');
            div.id = id;
            div.style = style;
            document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(div);
        }

    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <% console.log(graphs.name) %>
    <% console.log(graphs.myData) %>

    <p>
        <!-- HTML content goes here -->
        Hello
    </p>
    <ul>
        <%graphs.myData.forEach((item)=> { %>
            <li>
                I had <%=item[1] %> slices of <%=item[0]%> pizza </br>
            </li>
            <%})%>
    </ul>

</body>
</body>

</html>
```